# ng-repeat final callback event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to write a callback method which will be triggered everytime ng-repeat is called.

Got a couple of options from the internet

**1. ng-init on ng-repeat**

Here the method is called using ng-init property

```
<ol ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: sortCol:true" ng-init="$last && callMethod()">
```

**2. Using a custom directive**

HTML:

```
<ol ng-repeat="record in records| orderBy: 'name'" on-last-repeat>
```

AngularJs

```
  angular.module('myapp', [])  
    .directive('onLastRepeat', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.$last) setTimeout(function(){
                scope.$emit('onRepeatLast', element, attrs);
            }, 1);
        };
    })

.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.records = [];
    $scope.$on('onRepeatLast', function(scope, element, attrs){
        //work your magic
    });
    $http.get('/path/to/record.json')
      .success(function(data) {
          $scope.records = data;
      })
  });
```

But my problem would be both of them triggered only once initally(as the name ng-init suggests obviously). I want the method to be called whenever there is a change in the sortColumn or sortOrder(asc or desc) or the data (records). But both the above methods doesnt resolve my issue.

Help is appreciated much??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since watch only watches for reference change, I think your solution would be **$watchCollection()**

Comment: you can make a deep watch ( like object in object ) with the "true" param like this : 
scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {  ... },true);

Comment: watchCollection is used to watch multiple variables in scope

Comment: watch with the True param is much more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

For the records change. you have trying use $watch method?

```
$scope.$watch('records.length', function(newArray, oldArray){
    //Do something
},true);
```

Comment: orderBy is not altering the length of the original list or the order of the list. So how is the watch is going to trigger me the event..

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue with the below code:

**HTML:**

```
<ol ng-repeat="record in ($parent.newItems = (records | orderBy: sortCol:true))">
```

**AngularJs:**

```
$scope.$watchCollection('newItems ', function(newCollection, oldCollection) {
        newCollection && newCollection.length>0 && $scope.doSomething();
});
```